# Change database after login

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, database, login, aws

I  have instance of databases based on Magento admin users in **AWS** server.

I need to load **different** database after login user based on login.

I have find configuration but not find how to connect another instance after login.

Can any one have better idea how to change database instance after admin user login ?

or any chances to change database name after login.

Comment: So you want to login to Magento Admin, then change to a completely different Magento database based on that user?